# SBT won't resolve transitive dependency against any repository except Typesafe's

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I have a transitive dependency that just won't resolve and I'm tearing my hair out over this.

The specific dependency is `org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0-beta-2!wagon-provider-api.jar` though I'm not sure which direct dependency is including it.

The file is alive and well on the default Maven repo.  For some reason, however, SBT just refuses to check there for it though it's happy to look there for other dependencies:

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0-beta-2!wagon-provider-api.jar (52ms)
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-beta-2/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0-beta-2!wagon-provider-api.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0-beta-2!wagon-provider-api.jar
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Mar 23, 2013 7:22:05 PM
```

I've deleted `.ivy2`, `.m2` and `.sbt` from my home directory.  I've run `sbt update`.  I've run `play clean` and `play clean-all` over and over.  Runnings `resolvers` from the SBT prompt shows the Maven repo is in the list.

I've tried downloading the jar and adding it to my Ivy cache, my Ivy repository, my Play! repository.

What's left to try?

My Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "conspire"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
    "org.apache.cayenne.plugins" % "maven-cayenne-plugin" % "3.0.2",
    "org.objectstyle.ashwood" % "ashwood" % "2.0",
    "commons-collections" % "commons-collections" % "3.1",
    "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6",
    "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    externalResolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome+"/.m2/repository",
    resolvers ++= Seq(DefaultMavenRepository,
                      "Objectstyle repository" at " http://objectstyle.org/maven2/")
  )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
resolvers := // which overrides current resolvers
```

instead of

```
resolvers ++= // which appends to current resolvers
```

Don't ask me for explanation though, cause I have no idea why it works. Just had a similar issue with JUnit and [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/32KHF25b0IE) suggested doing it so, which helped...

Comment: sbt always resolves from resovlers in the order specified.  Whay may be happening is there is a bad ivy.xml/pom.xml file confusing sbt in one of these repositories, so it thinks it HAS to pull that from the first place it found it, which is actually a bad repository.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
resolvers :=
```

(which has the downside of not permitting multiple resolvers.) I have found that

```
resolvers +=
```

works fine, and does not exhibit the bug from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. But SBT would even search in the maven repo and the link it said does not work, actually works.

I solved it by moving my own dependencies before the default play stuf:

**BEFORE**

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.32"
  )
```

**AFTER**

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.32",
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc    
  )
```

Hope this helps someone else. Cheers